# How to avoid overflow?(put overflow on a new line)

Tags: css

I want to stop a div from overflowing. Currently it's overflowing to the right when there's no `<br>`'s until the div ends.

I don't want to create any scrollbars. Just want to break the line when it reaches the end of the div.
the CSS Div

```
#blog
{
border:#FFFFFF solid;
color:#FFFFFF;
width:760px;
min-height:100px;
border-color:#FFF;
border-width:thin;
float:left;
display: inline;
position:static;
z-index:1;
font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
background:#454545;
overflow:inherit;
}
```

I have messed around with the overflow property for some time now and i don't know what to enter into it to do what i want(or is it even possible)

Comment: Overflow can occur for many reasons.  Without seeing what the content within `#blog`, it is hard to tell.  Why don't you post some HTML and more CSS? and create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Is what you need

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2jc7n/)

Comment: What happens if the cause of the over flow is a large image in the blog post?

Comment: hmm, I'll try, we'll have to see

Comment: @MarcAudet then you need to set `overflow:hidden` so that the rest of the image wont leak. If you want the whole image to show then you need to adjust the width and height.

Comment: thanks, It'll take 10 minutes to select the answer. I really should Have done my research better, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content, these options are applicable:

- *white-space: preline* or *normal*. Actually, normal is the default one, it makes all extra spaces disappear and continue a text from a new line, when it meets the current line end. The lines are broken between words. Works nearly everywhere.
- *word-wrap: break-word* - this time, long words will be broken, if they don't fit into a line. Works nearly everywhere (and in Opera 10.5 and higher=) )